# How to search from specific post type with tags?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search, tags

**UPDATED:**

I have a Custom Post Type **Commercials**. This post type has a title and a video id. I want to search from this specific post type. Right now it returns result which matches the titles only, I also want it to return result from tags too. For example, let's say I have a commercial named *"**Lorem Ipsum Commercial**"* and this has a tag ***my tag***. *I want to it to return result if the searched value matches the title or the tag.* This is as far I got.

function.php

```
function searchCommercial($query) {
  if ( $query -> is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    if( isset($_GET['post_type']) ) {
      $type = $_GET['post_type'];
      if( $type == 'commercials' ) {
        $query -> set( 'post_type', array('commercials') );
        /*
        $terms = explode(' ', $query->get('s'));
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            'relation'=>'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'=>'post_tag',
                'field'=>'slug',
                'terms'=>$terms
            )
        ));*/
      }
    }
  }
  return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchCommercial' );
```

Search form:

```
<form role="search" method="GET" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
  <label>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="commercials">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

search.php

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( isset($_GET['post_type']) ) {
      $type = $_GET['post_type'];
      if ( $type == 'commercials' ) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/content-commercilas' );
      }
    }
  endwhile;
endif;
```

I've been trying to solve this for two days, any help would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
post type codes

```
add_action('init', registering_commercial);
function registering_commercial() {
  $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Commercials' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Commercial' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'Commercials' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => __( 'Commercial' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Commercial' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Commercial' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Commercial' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Commercial' ),
        'view_items'         => __( 'View Commercials' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Commercials' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Commercial' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Commercial:' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Commercial found.' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Commercial found in Trash.' ),
    'item_published'     => __( 'Commercial is published.' ),
    'item_updated'       => __( 'Commercial successfully updated!' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description for Commercials.' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'commercials' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies'         => array( 'commercial_category', 'post_tag' )
    );

  register_post_type( 'commercials', $args );
}
```

Category Codes:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_commercial_category', 0 );

function create_commercial_category() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Commercial Categories' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Category' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Category' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Commercial Category' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'commercial-category' )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'commercial_category', array( 'commercials' ), $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are customizing the query you are telling it to search for posts that ALSO match a custom `tax_query` criteria. This would never work, logically speaking.

You said, "I want it to return a result if this **tag** is searched or if it matches the **title**" for which I understand ONE or ANOTHER.

I'll show you a completely different approach, using basically the following logic:

1. You said "This post type has a title and a video id" so I assume you are not going to use the field/column `post_excerpt` for the CPT `commercials`. You can add it to `supports`, but it is not required for this to work.
2. We can make use of the action `save_post` to force WordPress adding your post tags to the field `post_excerpt` of a Commercial. When you take a look at the code this will sound less confusing.
3. We know that WordPress by default searches the columns `post_title`, `post_excerpt` and `post_content` for a term when the query var `s` is present. So doing number 2 above would solve your issue, because WordPress would take care of the rest.

Getting our hands dirty... we will still need to use the `pre_get_posts` action (yes, not a filter):

```
/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 */
function searchCommercial( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() && ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
            $type = $_GET['post_type'];
            if ( $type == 'commercials' ) {
                $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'commercials' ) );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchCommercial' );
```

And for saving the post tags within the `post_excerpt` of a **Commercial**:

```
/**
 * Fires once a post has been created or updated.
 *
 * @param int     $post_id
 * @param WP_Post $post
 * @param bool    $update Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
 */
function add_post_tags_to_commercials( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $post->post_type != 'commercials' ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag' );

    if ( $post_tags ) {
        $tags_with_comma = [];

        /**
         * @var WP_Term $tag
         */
        foreach ( $post_tags as $tag ) {
            $tags_with_comma[] = $tag->name;
            $tags_with_comma[] = $tag->slug;
        }

        $tags_with_comma = implode( ',', $tags_with_comma );

        // Unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely.
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'add_post_tags_to_commercials', 20 );

        wp_update_post(
            array(
                'ID'           => $post_id,
                'post_excerpt' => $tags_with_comma, // The tags will be saved within the `post_excerpt` column.
            )
        );

        // Re-hook this function.
        add_action( 'save_post', 'add_post_tags_to_commercials', 20, 3 );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_post_tags_to_commercials', 20, 3 );
```

The 2 snippets above can be placed within your **functions.php** file.

**Notice:**

- If you are using Guttenberg for your CPT `commercials`, you may have issues attaching post tags to it. Until now, WP version 5.2.1, is still having trouble attaching tags to a post using the AJAX process.
- You have to save all of your **Commercials** again. I hope it's just a few.
- Consider adding the string `excerpt` to your `commercials` `supports` as it would make it easier for you to see what's been added to the `post_excerpt` column:

```
'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', `excerpt` ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborated answer. This will be an interesting way of solving the issue. I'll keep this one in mind, I would upvote your answer, but I do not have enough reputation for upvote. If I cannot find a better method I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove

```
$_GET['post_type']
```

Please use below code i think you might help :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()         // Only target front end,
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && $q->is_search()     // Only target the search page
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', ['commercials'] );

        $terms = explode(' ', $q->get('s'));

        $q->set('tax_query', array(
            'relation'=>'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'=>'post_tag',
                'field'=>'slug',
                'terms'=>$terms
            )
        ));
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it's still now working. I've attached the post type registering codes. Is there any change needs to be done there?