# Facing problem with tax_query results

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts, tax-query

I need to get search results for posts on the basis of post-category(must) and posts-tags(optional).
The process is like:

1. search for a string e.g. "bananas"
2. the category is always static
3. need to check banana term in post-title, descriptions and in post-tags

Currently I am using multiple tax_query but it shows results only in (tags) or in (post-title, descriptions). But I need the combined results.

Here is my code:

```
    $catgory = 'case-definitions';
    $terms = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);
    $args = array(
        's' => $_GET['s'],
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'  => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category', 
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $catgory
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $terms
                )
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category', 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $catgory
            ),
        )
    );
```

Can anyone please help me out to correct me?  Much appreciated!

Comment: where is `$catgory` defined? Are you sure you meant to use `AND` in the inner clause? It makes sense as a human saying it out loud, but it doesn't make sense in a strict boolean logic sense that a computer would use. For your inner clause to match it must have" _both_ a category and a tag that have all of those terms", whereas I suspect you meant "a category _or_ a tag that have at least one of those terms"

Comment: Also, if a post has `banana` in the title, but does not have a category or term named `banana` then this won't find it, because you've specified `tax_query`, you can't do both at the same time with `WP_Query`

Comment: Are you starting from scratch with a new query for the search? Perhaps it would be more efficient to modify the search query to restrict its taxonomy — with either pre_get_posts() or a 'posts_search' filter — as the existing standard search query should handle your #1 and #3 needs for you.

Comment: @StudioAl can you please suggest a solution, please!

Comment: @TomJNowell then what is the best to achieve this?

Comment: Just find a trick [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339106/214325) to achieve what I need.
Thanks [Filip](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/84657/filipecsweb)